# Запятая между союзом и вводным словом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> У нас из общего только фамилия, да(,) возможно(,) что ребенок.

Правильно ли обособлено вводное слово в данном случае? Или после "да" не должно быть запятой?

Comment: Убираем вводное слово. Получаем: "да что ребенок"(?!). Что-то тут не так.

Comment: С этого и начал: убрал вводное. И понял, что тут что-то не так. Получается, что между "да" и вводным не нужна запятая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**У нас из общего только фамилия, да возможно что ребенок.**

Другой вариант: **У нас из общего только фамилия, да еще ребенок.**

В обоих случаях обособленный член предложения имеет **присоединительное значение**, а союзы ДА ЕЩЕ, ДА ВОЗМОЖНО ЧТО – это союзные аналоги, которые, кроме основного присоединительного союза ДА, могут включать в свой состав **наречия, местоимения, вводные слова и др.**

Answer (score 2):

> У нас из общего только фамилия, да(,) возможно(,) что ребенок.

Я бы выбрал такой вариант:

***У нас из общего только фамилия — да возможно, что ребенок.***

Здесь ***возможно*** — не вводное слово, а предикативное наречие (наречие в функции сказуемого).

Ср. с вариантом без придаточного (начинающегося со "что"):

***У нас из общего только фамилия — да, возможно, ребенок.***

Здесь ***возможно*** — вводное.